# Why does input type url accept a malformed URL?

Tags: html, forms, validation, url

Why does

```
<input type="url" />
```

when you to enter a value of `http:google.com` without the forward slashes, count the result as valid? It'll also allow `http:s`

http://jsfiddle.net/cFnUu/

Comment: It simply does not regard the http as the protocol -> the general url pattern is scheme://username:password@domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id

Comment: `http:s` though would surely still be malformed regardless?

Comment: It could be valid as a relative URL, no?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-state-(type=url) According to the html5 specs for this that would be my guess

Comment: @isherwood according to spec, it has to be an absolute URL unless you add the attribute "mutable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it's not invalid. **Malformed, but not invalid**.

General URL notation:

```
scheme://user:pass@hostname:port/path?query=string#fragment_id
```

So your URL is still valid. It leads to nowhere, but it is valid.

#### Conclusion:

- Don't rely on HTML5's validation blindly, when needed, roll your own.